# Set timeout on Azure Storage operations

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

When working with Azure Storage I see there is a way to set a [timeout on blob operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-blob-service-operations) and [on table operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-table-service-operations) if you are working with REST.

However we are working with C# client provided via WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet package (v8.4.0). And I don't see any way to specify a timeout here

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1"); // local storage for testing
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
var blobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference("my/blob.pdf");
```

I've tried what looking through available properties/methods on `CloudBlobClient` and on `StorageAccount`, but did not find anything resembling timeout setting.

It would be ideal if I can set timout in one place (in connection string??) and that is used in all the operations. But how do I do this in C# client?

Comment: Have you tried using [`CloudBlobClient.DefaultRequestOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.defaultrequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobClient_DefaultRequestOptions)?

Comment: @DavidG Thank You for providing link to DefaultRequestOptions. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: @DavidG that might be the answer. I'll try on Monday and report back.

Comment: for followers in java it's `uploadWithResponse(BlobParallelUploadOptions options, Duration timeout, Context context)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do take a look at [`ServerTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.servertimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_ServerTimeout) property in [`BlobRequestOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet) class.So your code would be:

```
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1"); // local storage for testing
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
            container.CreateIfNotExists(new BlobRequestOptions()
            {
                ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90)
            });
```

Comment: I'll check it out, looks promising. Thanks.

Comment: Bro, any ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545223/executequerysegmentedasync-is-not-working-when-the-azure-table-has-more-records

Comment: @Pரதீப் ... Just answered it :)