# ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync is not working when the Azure table has more records

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to read the records from Azure table storage. I have a simple query while pulling the records

```
var isPagination = true;
var  combinedFilter = "groupCode eq '9THS'";
var query = new TableQuery<AzStorageEntityAdapter<T>>().Where(combinedFilter);

TableRequestOptions tableRequestOptions = new TableRequestOptions() 
                                            { ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90) };

do
{
    var segments = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken, tableRequestOptions, null);
    currentPageResult.AddRange(segments.Results.Select(s => s.InnerObject).ToList());
    continuationToken = segments.ContinuationToken;
}  while (continuationToken != null && !isPagination);;
```

It was working till the azure table had less number of records(10000) with say 3 to 4 distinct `Groupcodes`.

When the table size increased over 200000 records, the search will not return any records (i.e) `segments.Results` has zero records, but the `continuationToken` has values.

If I replace the the `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` with `ExecuteQuery` it returns the expected records. I tried to add `ServerTimeout`, `MaximumExecutionTime` nothing helped.

Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here :). It is expected behavior.

From [`Query Timeout and Pagination`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination):

> **A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 items
>   at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds**. If the
>   result set contains more than 1,000 items, if the query did not
>   complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
>   boundary, the response includes headers which provide the developer
>   with continuation tokens to use in order to resume the query at the
>   next item in the result set. Continuation token headers may be
>   returned for a Query Tables operation or a Query Entities operation.

Basically your query is doing a full table scan as you have not specified any `PartitionKey` in your query and it tries to search for matching records by going from top of the table to the bottom. Since it is not finding any matching entities in 5 seconds, it is simply returning the continuation token.

As to why `ExecuteQuery` is working is because it internally handles the continuation token. You can confirm it by tracing the request/response in Fiddler.

Comment: So I should reiterate till I get the result ?

Comment: Yes, you should. Other option would be to rethink about the design of your table. Ideally all of your queries must include a `PartitionKey`. If you think you're going to query on `groupCode` you may want to store a copy of the data with `groupCode` value as `PartitionKey`.

Comment: You may find this link useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide. Please see `Design for querying` section there.

Comment: Actually I didn't post the exact query. my `while` condition is like `while (continuationToken != null && !isPagination);` isPagination is always true so it coming out without looping. Just realized this mistake after reading your explanation. Man you are so helpful in Azure, literally life saver.

Comment: Also, I answered a similar question that you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809078/design-of-partitioning-for-azure-table-storage/15809364#15809364.

Comment: `Man you are so helpful in Azure, literally life saver. ` - <blush/> ... I am happy that I was able to help you out :).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll read the link you have shared. I have many filters actually.