# What is the best way to get Azure listBlobs in parts using Java

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

Good day. I use `com.azure:azure-storage-blob` dependency with Java 8. And I have a question about the performance of the program. To get all blobs:

```
BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .connectionString("connectionString")
        .buildClient();
client.getBlobContainerClient("containerName")
        .listBlobs(new ListBlobsOptions().setPrefix("prefix"), null)
            .stream()...
```

The snippet works well, but if I need to set a time limit instead of `null`, then error starts to appear:

```
Exception in thread "main" reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 1000ms in 'flatMap' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

The bottom line is that I need to read groups of objects and send them for further processing without waiting for all. Because the waiting time of 10 objects will definitely be less than 10000. I know there is `continuationToken`, but calling it on the returned collection will throw the exception mentioned above. Is there any optimal solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To know the complete details about the error, try enabling [**Storage logging**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?redirectedfrom=MSDN&tabs=dotnet) and check logs.

Make use of the below sample code from [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerclient.listblobs?view=azure-java-stable#overloads):

```java
ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions()
     .setPrefix("prefixToMatch")
     .setDetails(new BlobListDetails()
         .setRetrieveDeletedBlobs(true)
         .setRetrieveSnapshots(true));
 String continuationToken = "continuationToken";
 client.listBlobs(options, continuationToken, timeout).forEach(blob ->
     System.out.printf("Name: %s, Directory? %b, Deleted? %b, Snapshot ID: %s%n",
         blob.getName(),
         blob.isPrefix(),
         blob.isDeleted(),
         blob.getSnapshot()));
```

**Otherwise**, make use of **[`Duration.ofMinutes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267454/listing-blobs-in-azure-blobstorage-using-azure-java-sdk-v12-and-listblobs-is-e)**  in your code like below:

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(2);
containerClient.listBlobs(options, duration)
```

**If still the error occurs**, try changing the versions of Azure Java SDK.

**Reference**:

[c# - Set timeout on Azure Storage operations - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710047/set-timeout-on-azure-storage-operations)

[Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/15215](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/15215)